# Array values changing without reason

Tags: c, arrays, debugging

This is my code for [Project Euler: Problem 11](https://projecteuler.net/problem=11)

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
char stevila [1600] = "08022297381500400075040507785212507791084949994017811857608717409843694804566200814931735579142993714067538830034913366552709523046011426924685601325671370236912231167151676389419236542240402866331380244732609903450244753353783684203517125032988128642367102638406759547066183864706726206802621220956394396308409166499421245558056673992697177878968314883489637221362309750076442045351400613397343133957817532822753167159403800462161409535692163905429635314755588824001754243629855786560048357189070544443744602158515417581980816805944769287392138652177704895540045208839735991607975732162626793327986688366887576220720346336746551232639353690442167338253911249472180846293240627636206936417230238834629969826759857404361620733529783190017431497148868116235705540170547183515469169233486143520189196748";
int stevilaGrid [20][20];
int stevilaRacunanje[4][4];
int stevecPoStevilih = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
        stevilaGrid[i][j] = (stevila[stevecPoStevilih] - 48)*10 + stevila[stevecPoStevilih + 1] - 48;
        stevecPoStevilih += 2;
    }
}

int rezultat [10];
int najvecji = 0;
int trenutni;
int temp = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 17; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 17; j++) {

        //problems start here
        for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
            for (int l = 0; l < 5; l++) {
                temp = stevilaGrid[i + k][j + l];
                stevilaRacunanje[k][l] = temp;
            }
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
            rezultat[k] = stevilaRacunanje[k][0] * stevilaRacunanje[k][1] * stevilaRacunanje[k][2] * stevilaRacunanje[k][3];
            rezultat[k+4] = stevilaRacunanje[0][k] * stevilaRacunanje[1][k] * stevilaRacunanje[2][k] * stevilaRacunanje[3][k];
        }
        rezultat[8] = stevilaRacunanje[0][0] * stevilaRacunanje[1][1] * stevilaRacunanje[2][2] * stevilaRacunanje[3][3];
        rezultat[9] = stevilaRacunanje[0][3] * stevilaRacunanje[1][2] * stevilaRacunanje[2][1] * stevilaRacunanje[3][0];
        for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
            trenutni = rezultat[k];
            if(trenutni > najvecji){
                najvecji = trenutni;
            }
        }
    }
}
printf("Najvecji zmnozek: %d", najvecji);

return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

First I convert the string of numbers into a 2D int array.

Then I try to divide the grid into smaller 4x4 squares with which I can work more easily. That is where the problems start (as marked in the code).

At the very beginning `(*i=0,j=0;k=4,j=0*)` something strange starts to happen. The values in `*stevilaGrid[][]*` start to change randomly and seemingly without a reason.

Can somebody please explain this to me. I have tested this behavior on Windows with Cygwin 64bit and Ubuntu with GCC 64bit.

Comment: You're going out of bounds on your array indexing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[i + k][j + l];
```

When `i==16` and `k==4` or `j==16` and `j==4` you'll be hitting element `[20]`
Your array only goes 0...19